# Will my last login be seen in WhatsApp if I'm not login for a month

Tags: whatsapp

Will my contacts see my last seen in WhatsApp even though I didn't use it for a month now? How will it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have [enabled your last seen](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23225461/?category=5245250) then it will show to your contacts whenever you were logged-in last time.

From [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/20971848/):

> **Last Seen** tell you the last time your contacts were using WhatsApp.
>
> **Last Seen** refers to the last time the contact used WhatsApp. Through our privacy settings, you have the option to control who can see your **Last Seen**.

It looks like this:

[image]
<sup>Image source: Google</sup>